# Pass DataGrid row to code behind when a member of the row is modified

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that gets the Name, Age, and IsFriend values from a List. I formatted my columns this way:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Path=Age}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Friend">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsFriend, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Checked="CheckBox_ValueChanged"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

In my CheckBox_ValueChanged code behind, I'd like to be able to get the Name of the person whose IsFriend CheckBox was selected. This is a rough sketch of my code behind:

```
private void CheckBox_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    //string name = Get the name that corresponds to the checkBox
    //Perform actions using the checkbox and name
}
```

I'm not sure if I should be passing the row to the CheckBox_ValueChanged method (or how to do that), or if there would be a simpler way to just get the Name using data binding or something similar in the XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to `checkBox's DataContext` and from it you can get the `Name` property -

```
private void CheckBox_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    string name = (checkBox.DataContext as YourClassName).Name;
}
```

`YourClassName` is the class name containing Name, Age, IsFriend properties.